# Error when i'm running `transactionResponse` function in the frontend(Vanilla JavaScript)

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, solidity, ethers.js

I'm learning how to interact with the front end, and i have two buttons called `connect` and `fund` and the wallet i have is metamask.

When i run my front-end code and after connecting to the wallet i get this error:

```
inpage.js:1 MetaMask - RPC Error: [ethjs-query] while formatting outputs from RPC '{"value":{"code":-32603,"data":{"code":-32000,"message":"Received invalid block tag 5. Latest block number is 3"}}}' {code: -32603, message: `[ethjs-query] while formatting outputs from RPC '{…nvalid block tag 5. Latest block number is 3"}}}'`}
(anonymous) @ inpage.js:1
(anonymous) @ inpage.js:17
_runReturnHandlers @ inpage.js:17
_processRequest @ inpage.js:17
await in _processRequest (async)
_handle @ inpage.js:17
handle @ inpage.js:17
_rpcRequest @ inpage.js:1
(anonymous) @ inpage.js:1
request @ inpage.js:1
(anonymous) @ ethers-5.6.esm.min.js:22986
send @ ethers-5.6.esm.min.js:23058
(anonymous) @ ethers-5.6.esm.min.js:20411
Promise.then (async)
sendUncheckedTransaction @ ethers-5.6.esm.min.js:20396
(anonymous) @ ethers-5.6.esm.min.js:20433
fulfilled @ ethers-5.6.esm.min.js:20144
Promise.then (async)
step @ ethers-5.6.esm.min.js:20159
(anonymous) @ ethers-5.6.esm.min.js:20161
__awaiter$a @ ethers-5.6.esm.min.js:20141
sendTransaction @ ethers-5.6.esm.min.js:20429
(anonymous) @ ethers-5.6.esm.min.js:12901
fulfilled @ ethers-5.6.esm.min.js:12563
Promise.then (async)
step @ ethers-5.6.esm.min.js:12578
(anonymous) @ ethers-5.6.esm.min.js:12580
__awaiter$4 @ ethers-5.6.esm.min.js:12560
(anonymous) @ ethers-5.6.esm.min.js:12889
fund @ srcipt.js:36
srcipt.js:41 Uncaught (in promise) {code: -32603, message: `[ethjs-query] while formatting outputs from RPC '{…nvalid block tag 5. Latest block number is 3"}}}'`, stack: '{\n  "code": -32603,\n  "message": "[ethjs-query] wh…hfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/common-4.js:19:37935'}
```

and my contract throws this error:

```
eth_blockNumber (3)
eth_getTransactionCount

  Received invalid block tag 5. Latest block number is 3

eth_blockNumber
eth_feeHistory

  Received invalid block tag 5. Latest block number is 3
```

Can someone help me out with this

When i click on the `fund` button i want an output in the console like "Funding some amount..."